# What is the real, day-to-day operational difference between Vista Home Premium and Ultimate?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, operating-system, vista64

I'm about to jump to a new machine that has Vista Home Premium 64 installed. I do development with VS2008. I have an Ultimate 64 license and disc so I can repave if I have to.

What are the day-to-day operational differences between Home Premium and Ultimate?  I know that IIS7 is supposed to be "stripped-down" but what does that really mean?

What about networking and authorization?

Comment: Excuse me, but ...how is that programming related?

Comment: Well, the installed IIS7, and how well it works with Visual Studio 2008 make this a valid "programming tools" questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big items for me are that Ultimate has domain join capabilities, and also remote desktop support - both of those features are left out of Home Premium.

Other than that - the Ultimate edition is pretty much a union of the features in Business and Home Premium editions.

I use the Ultimate edition for my development laptops, and the Business edition for my workstations - and have had no issues with IIS on either of those versions.

Comment: I can live without remote desktop and just use Live Mesh instead, but the domain join is harder to go without.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it's Microsoft Tinker, a game that came with the Ultimate extras last year ;)

Other than that and Dreamscene (you know, animated desktop backgrounds, absolutely essential for VS developers), I didn't miss any features on Home Premium. I didn't know that Home Premium doesn't have RDP and Domain Join capabalities, but didn't need those two features on my Home Premium machine anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the 64 bits , I couldn't find drivers for some hardware (SmartCards, Security Tokens, etc... ), it was only available for 32 bits for some OEMs